# Is there a hidden "C'est" in this sentence?

Tags: abréviations

Can you help me understand the following sentence which is highlighted. It seems not to have a verb or can we say that there is a hidden "**C'est...**"?

"Un mystérieux objet rocheux ayant la forme d’un cigare détecté en octobre provient bien d’un autre système solaire. **Une observation sans précédent qui a été confirmée lundi 20 novembre par des astronomes.**"

Source: http://www.lemonde.fr/cosmos/video/2017/11/21/voici-oumuamua-le-premier-asteroide-venu-d-un-autre-systeme-solaire-observe-par-les-scientifiques_5218151_1650695.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Un mystérieux objet rocheux ayant la forme d’un cigare détecté en octobre provient bien d’un autre système solaire,{***comma***} **une observation** sans précédent qui a été confirmée lundi 20 novembre par des astronomes.
>
> {or}: Un mystérieux objet rocheux ayant la forme d’un cigare détecté en octobre provient bien d’un autre système solaire,{***comma***} **observation** sans précédent qui a été confirmée lundi 20 novembre par des astronomes.

You could just as well join the two sentences together  with a comma, since the idea of "***which is*** an observation ..." is perceived here. You could also drop an indefinite article "une" if you wanted to emphasise how extraordinary this observation is, compared to others.